# Variable elimination - can I start from the middle of the network

Tags: inference, bayesian-network

I read that while doing `inference in Bayesian network with variable elimination`, any order will do.

Say I want to have the below network, where every random variable can be T/F with given probabilities given its parents state.

I want to calculate P(B=T), and I want to eliminate P(A) first. Can I do that?

I started by writing:

$P(B) = \sum_a\sum_e\sum_j\sum_mP(B=T)P(E)P(A|B,E)P(J|A)P(M|A) =$

$\sum_e\sum_j\sum_mP(B=T)P(E)\sum_aP(A|B,E)P(J|A)P(M|A)$

and now I'm stuck :(

Can you show me explicitly how do I do this first factoring step?

Thanks.

[image: my_bn]

Answer (score 0):

This is a good text for understanding how simple it is: [UCLA](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~jtian/cs673/cs673_spring05/lectures/cs262a-5.pdf).

Apparently, what needs to be done is:

1. multiply (cartesian-join) the factors (probability tables) $P(A|B,E)$, $P(J|A)$ and $P(M|A)$ by their common variables - in this case values of $A$, and multiply the 3 numbers for each row. We'll get a table with 5 columns and 2^5 = 32 rows.
2. Sum out A - sum each 2 records with same values of $B,E,J,M$ and different values for $A$ (T,F), and get a table with 4 columns and 16 rows.